# How to make changes in the html frontend when a doPost is triggered in google apps script

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-apps-script

I am creating a web app that displays orders from a third party app (woocommerce) in real time.

I have a doPost that listens from a webhook of a third party app (woocommerce) whenever a new order is created. How do I make changes in the front end html whenever a payload comes?

My doPost

```
function doPost(e) {

  let newOrder = e.postData.contents;

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "xx.xx@xx.com",
    subject: "Call Sucessful",
    htmlBody: "Data: <br>" + JSON.stringify(newOrder)
  });


  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(newOrder));
}
```

I tested this and the email is working, I just need a way for this event to be listened from the front end html so that I can update the html content with the new data (newOrder).

Any other method which could accomplishes the goal which is to 'update the html frontend with the latest order' is also appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for real time changes in frontend you have to use socket programing with socketIo fir example, this help to open lossless connection between front end and your server then whatever added to your data base emit it to frontend

Comment: Thanks! I'll look how I can integrate it with google apps script.

Comment: After looking for related articles I think polling is my best option. Based from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370977/google-app-scripts-and-websocket) I think google apps script does support web socketing